# Can I set a Parse Object Pointer with the ObjectID

Tags: parse-platform

I have a custom cloud code method to create a parse object.  I'm doing that so I can validate the uniqueness of a few pointer objects, etc.

When I create the object I need to create, can I set the non validated pointers via the object id I get from the client side?

Something like 
     object.set("user", "someuserid");

I'd like to avoid doing the extra find queries if I can when I already have the id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can so long as you create a new pointer and assign the objectId.

```
var Foo = Parse.Object.extend("Foo");
var pointerToFoo = new Foo();
pointerToFoo.id = "myObjectId";
```

There is also a shortcut you can use called [createWithoutData](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_createWithoutData)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Still works 7 years later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is one simple shortcut method
you just pass objectId to createWithoutData function

Parse.User.createWithoutData(req.body.objectId);